# Timeout for JedisConnectionFactory

Tags: java, redis, jedis

Is there a way to configure Read timeout in `JedisConnFactory` as we have for `HttpRequestFactory`? I've configured `JedisConnFactory` with timeout property as below. Does it include both **Connection timeout** and **Read timeout**?

```java
final JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
redisConnectionFactory.setHostName(redisHost);      
redisConnectionFactory.setTimeout(10000);
redisConnectionFactory.setPort(port);
redisConnectionFactory.setUsePool(true);
redisConnectionFactory.afterPropertiesSet();

@Bean(name = "redisCacheManager")
    public CacheManager cacheManager(final RedisTemplate<String,Object> redisTemplate) {
        final RedisCacheManager manager = new RedisCacheManager(redisTemplate());
        manager.setDefaultExpiration(Long.parseLong(expiryInSecs));
        return manager;
    }

    @Bean(name="redisTemplate")
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
        final RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<String, Object>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory());
        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(stringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(stringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(stringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setHashValueSerializer(stringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();
        return redisTemplate;
    }
```

Comment: Are you using springboot?

Comment: did below answer help you out?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [JedisClientConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/jedis/JedisClientConfiguration.html). It has a builder [JedisClientConfigurationBuilder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/jedis/JedisClientConfiguration.JedisClientConfigurationBuilder.html) which contains
has both **Connection** timeout and **Read** timeout properties separetely.

```
JedisClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = JedisClientConfiguration.builder().readTimeout(readTimeout).
                connectTimeout(connectTimeout).build();
```

You can then use one of the [JedisConnectionFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/jedis/JedisConnectionFactory.html#JedisConnectionFactory-org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisStandaloneConfiguration-org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisClientConfiguration-) constructors which accepts JedisClientConfiguration.

Comment: Thanks, Yes it worked after switching to version 2.1.6.RELEASE. We were using 1.4.4.RELEASE version earlier. But now, I'm not able to create instance of RedisCacheManager with RedisTemplate. Updated the question with .code

Comment: You should not edit question to completely change the context. The solution was posted for your original problem. You have edited the question to change the context. You should post a new question or add comments if you have a new query, rather than changing the context of existing question. You should edit current question to add/edit details without changing your original problem statement

Answer (score 0):

Extend from JedisConnectionFactory and override the afterPropertiesSet method as shown below:

```
public class CustomJedisConnectionFactory extends JedisConnectionFactory {

    private int connectionTimeout;

    private int readTimeout;

    // override super class constructors if required.

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {

        super.afterPropertiesSet();
        final JedisShardInfo jedisShardInfo = this.getShardInfo();

        if (Objects.nonNull(jedisShardInfo)) {

            jedisShardInfo.setConnectionTimeout(getConnectionTimeout());
            jedisShardInfo.setSoTimeout(getReadTimeout());
        }
    }
}
```

Create an instance of CustomJedisConnectionFactory and set the "connectionTimeout" and "readTimeout" fields.

```
CustomJedisConnectionFactory factory = new CustomJedisConnectionFactory();
factory.setHostName(host);
factory.setPort(port);
factory.setConnectionTimeout(connectionTimeout);
factory.setReadTimeout(readTimeout);
```

Comment: Do we need to set these properties if we are using Jedis with Redis server deployed on Amazon Elastic cache